# Most efficient way to build a tree (insertion of nodes)?

Tags: data-structures, tree, insert, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to build a binary search tree where the time complexity for adding a node to the tree is better than O(n) since I'll be adding a lot of data. The data shouldn't be sorted before building the tree because the problem that I'm solving requires the data to be added in the tree in the EXACT same order that it is inputed from the console.

Comment: More efficient than what? Nobody can answer this question because you are asking to be to something. Now if you are asking what is the best way to build binary tree, you should change the question.

Comment: more efficient meaning with better time complexity than O(n)

Comment: Why not keep two set of data? A linked list of the order of data input. And binary tree for searching. And then you can always rebuild the tree anytime.

Comment: In a classical binary search tree, the average insertion time is `O(log(n))`, but in the worst case it'll be `O(n)`, independently of your implementation choices. If you want a `O(log(n))` worst case insertion time guarantee, you'll need to use a balanced search tree implementation, such as red-black tree for instance.

Answer (score 1):

A simple [binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) has indeed a worst case insertion time in `O(n)` (even if in average, for unsorted 'random' data, the insertion time is going to be `O(log n)`).

There exists variations of the binary search tree, such as the [AVL tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree), or the [red-black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree), which are self balancing, meaning that their depth will never be superior to `O(log n)`.
They offer the guarantee that the insertion will ve done in `O(log n)` regardless of the input (even sorted input will be inserted in `O(log n)`), but on the other hand their implementation is more tedious and error prone than the very simple and straight forward binary search tree.

As for not sorting the data *before* inserting it in a binary search tree: sorting data before inserting it in a binary search tree (or the variations I mentioned) is the worst thing you could do. The sorting would not be too costy by itself (`O(n log n)`), but it creates the worst case scenario for any of those structures (the binary search tree will be a single branch of length `n`; and in the self balancing trees, it maximizes the cost of seelf-balancing operations).